# How to make a global variable within a npm package function

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, global-variables

Im using npm papercut https://www.npmjs.com/package/papercut and I want to get access to a variable value that is within a papercut function. This is what I have so far.

I want to get access to the value of the variable Img outside the function to the variable NewImg here Im trying to do so using a global variable. Anyone see my problem or have any suggestions.

```html
var NewImg = {}

uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
  var Img = images.avatar
  NewImg.input = Img
  console.log(Img);
})
console.log(NewImg.input)
```

this logs out undefined

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some asynchronous code. It's likely that the callback isn't called before your `console.log()` so your `NewImg.input` is undefined.

Also `var NewImg.input = Img` is not syntactically correct, remove `var`.

### UPDATE

Read more about asynchronous javascript: [Asynchronous Javascript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)

```
var NewImg = {}

uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
  // I'm a callback function in an asynchronous method!
  // I will run sometime in the future!
  var Img = images.avatar
  NewImg.input = Img
  console.log(Img);
})
// Oh no! I ran before the callback function in the *asynchronous* method above, before NewImg.input is assigned any value
console.log(NewImg.input)
```

Comment: I removed the var and it still getting undefined

Comment: @DavidRamirez What about it being asynchronous? Move the log inside the callback function. `console.log` is called before `NewImg.input` ever receives a value.

Comment: I moved the log inside the call back It logs a blank line

Comment: @DavidRamirez Sounds like you have your solution for `NewImg.input` being undefined. I suspect both logs are returning blank lines. Make sure you are using the `uploader.process` method correctly.

Comment: I just noticed that the log outside is getting logged before the log inside the callback would you know why. And the `uploader.process` is working well I can upload images Also the log outside is undefined and the log inside is blank

Comment: @DavidRamirez yes, I do. Because `uploader.process` is _asynchronous_. Check out my updated answer

Comment: where is your updated answer and can you post a snippet

Comment: @DavidRamirez Please, look at the update on this answer. You need to research _asynchronous_ code. The key here is **_asynchronous_**.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `var` inside a function, then you make new variable inside the function with the same name. So your code should be:

```
var NewImg = {}

uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
  var Img = images.avatar;
  NewImg.input = Img;
  console.log(Img);
  console.log(NewImg.input) 
})
```

Comment: I removed the var and it still getting undefined